# how to get this layout with multitail

Tags: linux, logging

I have a silly one for you
I know how to do this with multitail (`multitail -s 2 -sn 1,2 A.log B.log C.log`):

```
+-----------------------+------------+
|                       |            |
|                       |            |
|                       |            |
|                       |            |
|                       |            |
|                       |            |
|                       |            |
|                       +------------+
|                       |            |
|                       |            |
|                       |            |
|                       |            |
|                       |            |
|                       |            |
+-----------------------+------------+
```

but I'd like to do this:

```
+-------------------------------------------------+
|                                                 |
|                                                 |
|                                                 |
|                                                 |
|                 A.log                           |
|                                                 |
|                                                 |
|                                                 |
|                                                 |
|                                                 |
+------------------------+------------------------+
|                        |                        |
|                        |                        |
|           B.log        |         C.log          |
|                        |                        |
|                        |                        |
+------------------------+------------------------+
```

Is that possible and if so then how?